# ViewPager change to another page on textview click

Tags: android

I have used an example code from the following site:
http://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial

It works but I need to add another page where there is a textview one can click to go to one of the pages (for eg. BLUE page). I have put the TextView in the xml file with the 2 lines:
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="click"

I have also added the following incomplete method in the MainActivity.

```
public void click(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.change_page:

            //what do I need to add in here?

    }
}
```

I am not sure I am setting this up the right way. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: I have added another blank page in the beginning. In that page there is a line of text (which says go to BLUE page) which the user clicks and it should then bring up the BLUE page.

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.change_page : 
    mViewPager.setCurrentPage(yourpageindex);
    break;
case: R.id.another_text view: 
   //go to another page
```

Comment: Is this for another class? I want to go to another page within the viewpager. In this case the BLUE page.

Comment: I suppose the yourpageindex is the int value. But what is mViewPager?

Comment: Is your view pager which contains the fragments

Comment: I think in the example fragments are not used. Is there something else I should use?

Answer (score 0):

create another activity, and separate layout file, and use an explicit intent in the main activity, 
in the new layout file , use the desired ViewPager
probably this may work .

Answer (score 0):

as @hash-set suggested. `setCurrentPage(yourpageindex);` will do the trick.

all you need to know is what is index value of your BLUE page. and set it in place of yourpageindex.

**for Example :** let's assume index of Your Blue page is "1".

```
public void click(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.change_page:

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the example code on the website, what would I put in place of yourViewPager that you have suggested?

Comment: in website thy have take viewpage so in this case that would be `viewPager.setCurrentPage(1);` see my updated answer

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention one difference from the example. In my case I am using the viewPager in the action bar (toolbar).  The code for onCreateOptionsMenu is:                                                                                                                 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

Comment: long story short. it is instance of your `ViewPager`. it does't matter where you are using it. just excess `setCurrentPage(1);` with instance of your `ViewPager` you have declared. in website you mentioned, they have declared `ViewPager's` instance as viewpage.

Comment: In the onOptionsItemSelected the code is:                                                                                                                     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.change_location:                                                                                   viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));                                                                        return true;

Comment: When I add this line: viewPager.setCurrentPage(1);  the setCurrentPage is shown as error (in red). Any idea why this would be?

Comment: How can I send the code to you? Chat is not allowed for me at the moment.

Comment: vrund purohit, thanks for trying to help but I just found why it was giving the error. Instead of setCurrentPage(int) I had to write setCurrentItem(int). All good now.

Comment: sorry my bad. if i did't looked for that silly mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately now I have another question. In the blank page I need to put a button to start an audio with media controller. Should I set up another separate question for this?

Comment: yes.. and before asking go through some example and try to solve it by your self.